# How to keep Google Chrome always open with given URL from Windows Service using C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, process, windows-services

I'm developing a Windows Service to open a given URL in Google Chrome and time to time (using a timer) I have to check whether the Chrome browser is open with that given URL. I have already start the process with the URL.

How to reopen the the given URL if the URL is not opened from the browser.

I have done this in process level. 
My code as follows..

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer t = null;
        private static Process proc;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            t = new Timer();
            t.Interval = 1000;
            proc = Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://www.google.lk");
            t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + " Timer Ticking");
            if (proc.HasExited)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + " Chrome reopened");
                proc.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + " Chrome is Running");

                //If my url is not opened I need to open my url in a new tab.
                //{
                //   proc.Start();
                //}
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Windows service with timer? Why don't you just use [kiosk mode](https://www.sitepoint.com/google-chrome-kiosk-mode/) build into chrome?

Comment: @vasily.sib, Thanks for your recommendation. Is there a way to reopen the browser with kiosk mode if someone close it by pressing Alt+F4..?

Comment: Dozens of ways, just google a little.